# Is there a way to put multiple pivot tables in the same sheet from the same pivot cache?

Tags: vba, pivot-table

I'm trying to put two pivot tables into the same sheet but my second pivot table is not being created when I step into VBA. The code runs without any errors, but the second pivot table is never created. I'm looking to eventually add many pivot tables to the same sheet so any help with this would be appreciated.

I've tried setting two different caches, but I don't believe that will help solve this specific problem. I've also tried

```
Sub CreatePivottablewithVBA()

'Declare Variables
Dim Psheet As Worksheet
Dim DSheet As Worksheet
Dim PCache As PivotCache
Dim Ptable As PivotTable
Dim Ptable2 As PivotTable
Dim PRange As Range
Dim LastRow As Long
Dim LastCol As Long


'Insert a New Blank Worksheet
On Error Resume Next
Application.DisplayAlerts = False
Worksheets("PivotTable").Delete
Sheets.Add After:=ActiveSheet
ActiveSheet.Name = "PivotTable"
Application.DisplayAlerts = True
Set Psheet = Worksheets("PivotTable")
Set DSheet = Worksheets("Raw")

'Define Data Range
LastRow = DSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
LastCol = DSheet.Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
Set PRange = DSheet.Cells(1, 1).Resize(LastRow, LastCol)

'Define Pivot Cache
Set PCache = ActiveWorkbook.PivotCaches.Create _
(SourceType:=xlDatabase, SourceData:=PRange). _
CreatePivotTable(TableDestination:=Psheet.Cells(2, 2), _
TableName:="SalesbyYearMonth")

'Insert Blank Pivot Table
Set Ptable = PCache.CreatePivotTable _
(TableDestination:=Psheet.Cells(1, 1), TableName:="SalesbyYearMonth")

'Insert Row Fields
With ActiveSheet.PivotTables("SalesbyYearMonth").PivotFields("ck_complete_dt")
.Orientation = xlRowField
.Position = 2
End With

'Insert Data Field
With ActiveSheet.PivotTables("SalesbyYearMonth").PivotFields("total_amount")
.Orientation = xlDataField
.Position = 1
.Function = xlCount
.Name = "# of Sales"
End With

With ActiveSheet.PivotTables("SalesbyYearMonth").PivotFields("total_amount")
.Orientation = xlDataField
.Position = 2
.NumberFormat = "$#,##0.00"
.Function = xlSum
.Name = "Total Amount"
End With

With ActiveSheet.PivotTables("SalesbyYearMonth").PivotFields("total_amount")
.Orientation = xlDataField
.Position = 3
.Calculation = xlPercentOfTotal
.NumberFormat = "0.00%"
.Name = "% of Total"
End With

'Format Pivot Table
ActiveSheet.PivotTables("SalesbyYearMonth").ShowTableStyleRowStripes = True
ActiveSheet.PivotTables("SalesbyYearMonth").TableStyle2 = "PivotStyleMedium9"
PivotTable.DataOnRows = False



'Create PivotTable2
Set Ptable2 = PCache.CreatePivotTable(TableDestination:=Psheet.Cells(22, 2), TableName:="SalesPerCategory")


With ActiveSheet.PivotTables("SalesPerCategory").PivotFields("highest_categ_level")
.Orientation = xlRowField
.Position = 1
.Name = "Category"
    End With

With ActiveSheet.PivotTables("SalesPerCategory").PivotFields("highest_categ_level")
.Orientation = xlDataField
.Position = 1
.Function = xlSum
.Name = "Count of Categories"
    End With


End Sub
```

I don't receive any error messages but I expect to see both pivot tables created in the sheet PivotTable

Comment: `On Error Resume Next` -->> "I don't receive any error messages"

Comment: Step 1: remove `On Error Resume Next`. Step 2: run the code, then [edit] your post with the error number/message you're getting, and tell us what instruction is throwing the error. With `On Error Resume Next` ignoring every error that might happen, you can't debug anything.

Comment: oh very dumb mistake on my part. Ok, I removed On Error Resume Next. I get Run-time error '13': Type mismatch where I am setting my first Pivot CacheSet PCache = ActiveWorkbook.PivotCaches.Create _
(SourceType:=xlDatabase, SourceData:=PRange). _
CreatePivotTable(TableDestination:=Psheet.Cells(2, 2), _
TableName:="SalesbyYearMonth")

Comment: You're setting `PCache` to the return value from `CreatePivotTable` - that returned object is a pivot *table*, not a pivot *cache*...

Comment: @TimWilliams you da man, Tim. very fresh to vba